# EntityManager still null with both annotation or EntityManagerFactory method

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, jta

I have a Java EE project using JPA.
My tables are auto-generated by hibernate when my server is starting so my entites are correct.
I need now to insert / update data using an entitymanager.
When I use the annotated entity manager or the standard one using the entityManagerFactory I got the NullPointer exception.

my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

        <persistence-unit name="LogmonPU" transaction-type="JTA">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/LogmonDS</jta-data-source>
                <properties>
                        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
                        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
                        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my abstractDAO class :

```
package com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.ejb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 * @author benoit brayer
 *
 * @param <E>
 *            The class entity needed to be mapped
 * @param <PK>
 *            The primary key type for this class
 */
public abstract class AbstractDAO<E
extends Serializable, PK extends Serializable> {
    /** */
    private final transient Class<E> mEntityClass;
    /**
     * @param entityClass the entity needed to be mapped by the dao class
     */
    public AbstractDAO(final Class<E> entityClass) {
        mEntityClass = entityClass;
    }

    /**
     * @return the EntityManager object corresponding to the mapped entity class
     */
    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    /**
     * @return all objects mapped by entity
     */
    protected abstract Collection<E> getAll();

    /**
     * @param entity an instance of the entity needed to be add database
     */
    public final void create(final E entity) {
        final EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id of the desired entity object
     * @return the entity object matching the specified id
     */
    public final E getById(final PK id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(mEntityClass, id);
    }
}
```

my EJB used like my model :

```
package com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.ejb;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jpa.User;

/**
 * @author benoit brayer
 */
@Stateless(name = "userEJB")
public class UserEJB extends AbstractDAO<User, Long> {

    /** */
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "LogmonPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    /** */
    public UserEJB() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Collection<User> getAll() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u from WEB_USER u");
        return (Collection<User>) query.getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username matching the desired entity object
     * @return the entity object corresponding to the database row
     */
    public final User getUserByUsername(final String username) {
        Query query = em
                .createQuery("SELECT u from WEB_USER u where u.username = ?1")
                .setParameter(1, username);
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

Error log :

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jsf.index.IndexBean.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:677)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at com.c2alliance.commons.sso.client.filter.AllianceCASAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AllianceCASAuthorizationFilter.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.ejb.UserEJB.getUserByUsername(UserEJB.java:43)
    at com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jsf.controller.UserControllerBean.isUserFirstLogin(UserControllerBean.java:42)
    at com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jsf.controller.UserControllerBean.webAppUserAuthentication(UserControllerBean.java:69)
    at com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jsf.index.IndexBean.<init>(IndexBean.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    ... 59 more
```

thanks in advance.
Regards

**EDIT :**

The controller called my my JSF managed bean dealing with business logic : 
    package com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jsf.controller;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.ejb.UserEJB;
import com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jpa.User;

/**
 * @author benoit brayer
 */
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class UserControllerBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Generated attribute for Serialization.
     *
     * @attribute serialVersionUID serialisation id
     * @see java.io.Serializable
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** */
    private User mUser;

    /**
     * @return true if it is the user first login & false if the user has
     *         already an account
     * @param username
     *            the user username
     */
    public final boolean isUserFirstLogin(final String username) {
        Boolean firstLogin = true;
        UserEJB userEjb = new UserEJB();
        User user = userEjb.getUserByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            firstLogin = false;
        }
        return firstLogin;
    }


    /**
     * Operations called after getting the usename
     * of the user who logged-in using SSO.
     * @param username
     *            the user username
     */
    public final void webAppUserAuthentication(final String username) {
        User user = null;
        UserEJB userEjb = new UserEJB();
        if (isUserFirstLogin(username)) {
            user = new User();
            user.setUsername(username);
            userEjb.create(user);
        } else {
            user = userEjb.getUserByUsername(username);
        }
        this.setUser(user);
    }

    .... other stuff
```

my indexbean managed bean of my index.xhtml page:

```
/** JSF Facelet
 * @author Benoit Brayer
 * @imports java.io.Serializable;
 * @imports javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 * @imports javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
 * @import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
 * @import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 */
package com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jsf.index;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jsf.controller.UserControllerBean;

/**
 * JSF ManagedBean for index page.
 */
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "indexBean")
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * Generated attribute for Serialization.
     *
     * @attribute serialVersionUID serialisation id
     * @see java.io.Serializable
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Returns the name of the jsf Bean.
     */
    private String mNom = "indexBean";

    /** */
    private UserControllerBean userController = new UserControllerBean();

    /**
     * @return the name of the servlet
     */
    public final String getNom() {
        return mNom;
    }

    /** IndexBean constructor. */
    public IndexBean() {
         userController.webAppUserAuthentication((((HttpServletRequest)
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest())
         .getUserPrincipal()).toString());
    }

    ... other stuff
```

**I finally solve half of my problem using :**

```
private EntityManager em = (EntityManager) Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("LogmonPU")
        .createEntityManager();
```

instead of :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "LogmonPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

In my EJB files.

Adding theses lines into my persistence.xml :

```
<class>com.st.safir.LogMonitoring.jpa.User</class>
```

and

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"  value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" />
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
```

My entity manager is not more null but I still cant insert in database.
No row appear in my database after this.
My jboss log :

```
janv./17 15:20:19,710 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: 
janv./17 15:20:19,712 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     select
janv./17 15:20:19,715 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)         S_INC_TUSER.nextval 
janv./17 15:20:19,717 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     from
janv./17 15:20:19,719 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)         dual
```

Which is basically my sequence to ato-increment my rows using an oracle database.

Comment: Shouldn't `UserEJB` be annotated with `@Stateless` or `@Stateful`?

Comment: @Stateless(name = userEJB) was there before but for some reason I removed it unintentionally. Anyway, I added it again and this does not change anything. Thanks for the observation ;)

Comment: looks like you are accessing the UserEJB as a java class rather than looking it up an instance from the server.  Show the code for the JSP making the getUserByUsername call, but if it doesn't look up the bean from the server, the server cannot inject the EM into it.

Comment: Thanks Chris,

I am quite sure you have the right explaination for my problem.
I will add in my previous post all the files which are called before calling the getUserByUsername method.

I did not really understand what you mean by : "the server cannot inject the EM into it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVING FINALLY THE PROBLEM**

To solve finally the problem, I changed my persistence.xml like this :

```
<persistence-unit name="LogmonPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

I also use my entity manager like this from now :

```
public final User create(final User entity) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return entity;
}
```

That was exausted but I solved it finally -.-'
Thanks for the comments which helped me to sort it out.